# pushViewController not working read much online though

Tags: ios

Here is what code I get online, and it does work on previous project that I develop.But in this project, `self.navigationController` is null when I `NSLog` it, and guys online talked about add some code in delegate file, but I found nothing in previous project also I am not very clear what code should I add there. Anyone can give me a hand?

```
UIViewController *next = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewCollection"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `UINavigationController` is `nil`, it means that the view controller that you use (which you instantiate from a *Storyboard*) is *not actually embedded* within a `UINavigationController`.

In order to embed it into a `UINavigationController`, you need to drag and drop a `UINavigationController` into your *Storyboard* and then ctrl-drag from the `UINavigationController` to your custom view controller and set it as the `rootViewcontroller` of the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Hi, I am sure what you talked is really a great help me on the understanding how UINavigationController, and I just followed your step feel it more near from the rightness, but still null, do I need to write some code or anything?

Comment: just make sure the view controller is embedded inside a `UINavigationController`... (as an indicator if it worked, you can check whether the view controller has a navigation bar on top)

Comment: Yes it does have a navigation bar on top, but still cannot goto another page   correctly :(

Comment: there is a navigation bar but `self.navigationController` still is `nil`?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", self.navigationController);//2015-06-06 00:28:41.777 TutorialTest[55249:1104198] (null)

Answer (score 0):

as nburk said: you need a NavigationController with a RootViewController which is your view. and dont forget to set the NavigationController as Initial View Controller. This all is done in the IB.

[image]